# How to make 100% covered branches if foreach always finish with break

Tags: java, jacoco

So I have little problem, I want to make 100% covered branches on JaCoCo, but I have 1 of 2 missed branches in my for-each.

Here is my code (`lettersGroups` is list of `["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", ..., "VWX", "YZ"]`. Function `returnLettersGroups` divides alphabet on 3 letters and returns list.):

```
List<String> lettersGroups = returnLettersGroups();

for (Strin nameOfCountry : listOfCountries) {
        String firstLetter = StringUtils.getFirstLetter(nameOfCountry);
        for (String oneGroup : lettersGroups) { //Here I have "1 of 2 branches missed."
            if (oneGroup.contains(firstLetter.toUpperCase())) {
                //Do something.
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: When using a `for` loop, there are two branches : the program either goes in the loop or it doesn't. To cover all branches, you need to have two test cases : one where `returnLettersGroups` returns an empty list and one when it returns a non-empty list.

Comment: I assume "YX" is typo . shouldn't it be "YZ"?

Comment: Yes, my mistake:P I didn't copied it, I just wrote example ^^ And I have little problem, because list never will be empty :/ It would be empty only if I change returnLettersGroups function.

Comment: @Tunaki, from the JaCoCo point of view you're wrong. You just need normal loop termination, to get 100% coverage. You don't have to cover the case when loop is not executed at all.

Answer (score 4):

The missed branch is the normal termination of the inner loop, when `break` is not executed. More specifically, the call of `iterator.hasNext()` of implicit iterator created from `lettersGroups` always returned `true` in your code and you did not test the case when it returns `false`. You can cover this branch if your `listOfCountries` have the country which does not start with any latin letter. Probably in your case covering this branch is meaningless. While in general the number of covered branches is a good metric for your tests quality, aiming for 100% coverage is usually a waste of time.

Comment: Strongly agree with this.  It's principle of demonising returns. 10% of your code will be easy to test and give you huge returns (it's fiddly code with lots of corner cases and likely to be wrong). After that testing gets harder/lower return until the last 10% is difficult to test and obviously not going to go wrong and you'd get a much better return on investment working elsewhere in the code base